# How to start child cmd terminals in separate windows, from python script and execute scripts on them?

Tags: python, windows, parallel-processing, terminal, cmd

I have been trying rather unsuccesfully to open several terminals (though one would be enough to start with) from say an ipython terminal that executes my main python script. I would like this main python script to open as many cmd terminals as needed and execute a specific python script on each of them. I need the terminal windows to remain open when the script finishes.

I can manage to start one terminal using the command:

```
import os
os.startfile('cmd')
```

but I don't know how to pass arguments to it, like:

```
/K python myscript.py
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be done?

Cheers
H.H.

Answer (score 0):

Use subprocess module. Se more info at. Google>>python subprocess

Comment: I had a look at that but couldn't figure out how to create new terminal windows. It seems it starts the terminal in the same parent window.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

```
    import subprocess
    subprocess.check_output(["python", "c:\home\user\script.py"])
```

or

```
    subprocess.call(["python", "c:\home\user\script.py"])
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not create a new window, but just runs the code within the same window. How to change that command to achieve that?